# Как работает данный алгоритм?

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия

Вопрос конечно тупой, но я залип.
Есть код:

```
n=5
def F(n):
  print(n)
    if n // 3 !=0:
      F(n-1)
      F(n-3)
F(n)
```

Результатом которого является последовательность чисел

`5
 4
 3
 2
 0
 1
 2`

Почему выводится именно эти числа. Объясните почему после "0" выводятся положительные числа. Так же непонятно откуда в строчке 4 появилась цифра "2". Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это рекурсия, которая в случаях когда целочисленное деление на `3` возвращает не `0`, порождает еще два вызова рекурсии для разных значений от `n`.

Я накидал как будет выполняться рекурсия.

Значения `n` к номеру:

```
5 [1]
4 [2]
3 [3]
2 [4]
0 [5]
1 [6]
2 [7]
```

Дерево рекурсии с значениями и номерами:

```
                               5 (5//3=1) [1]
                             /              \
                 4 (4//3=1) [2]             2 (2//3=0) [7]
                 /           \
         3 (3//3=1) [3]   1 (1//3=0) [6]   
            /     \
2 (2//3=0) [4]  0 (0//3=0) [5]
```

Comment: У вас опечатка в слове случай

Answer (score 1):

```js
function F(n) {
  console.log("n =", n, ", div by 3 =", Math.floor(n / 3), Math.floor(n / 3)? ", go deeper" : ", go back");
  if (Math.floor(n / 3) != 0) {
    console.log("calling F with n - 1, n =", n);
    F(n - 1);
    console.log("calling F with n - 3, n =", n);
    F(n - 3);
  }
}
F(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Данная функция заканчивается, когда `n div 3` равен 0. Иначе говоря, переменная n должна иметь значения 0, 1 или 2.

```
1. n = 5; 5 div 3 = 1; Вызывается функция F(5-1).
2. n = 4; 4 div 3 = 1; Вызывается функция F(4-1).
3. n = 3; 3 div 3 = 1; Вызывается функция F(3-1).
4. n = 2; 2 div 3 = 0; Заканчиваем с первой рекурсией из п.3. Возвращаемся ко второй рекурсии.
5. Вызывается функция F(3-3).
6. n = 0; 0 div 3 = 0; Заканчиваем со второй рекурсией из п.3. Возвращаемся ко второй рекурсии в п.2.
7. Вызывается функция F(4-3).
8. n = 1; 1 div 3 = 0; Заканчиваем со второй рекурсией из п.2. Возвращаемся ко второй рекурсии в п.1.
9. Вызывается функция F(5-3).
10. n = 2; 2 div 3 = 0; Заканчиваем со второй рекурсией из п.1.

The end.
```